# I want to generate a qr code for a given Wifi SSID, after choosing security, and entering password in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, qr-code

'I want to generate a qr code for a given Wifi SSID, after choosing security, and entering password in Android Studio.'
The title of this question pretty much sums up my problem. I would truly appreciate anyone who can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this website/ article can help you:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-generate-qr-code-in-android/

The string you need to pass has this format:
`WIFI:S:<SSID>;T:<WPA|WEP|>;P:<password>;;`

Hope this will help you. If you need help just ask and I will try to set up a sample app.

Comment: In this article, do we have to input the WiFi ssid/password ourselves?